# Error while Generating Javadoc Kdoc for Kotlin Project using Dokka in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, javadoc, kotlin-dokka

I am using **Dokka** plugin to generate documentation for my kotlin project

Here is the plugin url **https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka**

I have followed the instructions this is how my **Project.gradle** looks like

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:0.9.15"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is how my **app/build.gradle** looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kk.testkotlindoc"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dokka {
    outputFormat = 'html'
    outputDirectory = "$buildDir/javadoc"
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

When I execute the below command to generate documentation

**./gradlew dokka**

It initially downloaded the necessary jar files after the process is completed it is giving me the below error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/KK/AndroidStudioProjects/TestkotlinDoc/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError-com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin
```

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

But I am unable to identify what is the ISSUE or What am I MISSING HERE

Please help me ..

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're running Dokka under an older JDK version. Dokka requires JDK 8. Please make sure that the environment variable JDK_HOME on your machine points to a JDK 8 installation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will change to JDK8. I am on it. Could you please let me know rest of the implementation is fine ?? Or Am I missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate Dokka documentatiton without Dokka plugin... Use [GradleMavenPush](https://github.com/Vorlonsoft/GradleMavenPush), it has `task androidDokka(type: Exec, dependsOn: dokkaInitializer)` and `task coreDokka(type: Exec, dependsOn: dokkaInitializer)`

```
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/Vorlonsoft/GradleMavenPush/master/maven-push.gradle'
```